# Broken Gallery animation

Tags: android, animation, gallery

I'm using Gallery in my layout. When I'm trying to change any view (not Gallery item) from OnItemSelected function, it affects on broken Gallery animation (jerk appears and it stops look smooth). I mean standard Gallery animation which appears after selecting another view in gallery.

```
mGallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
        mTextView1.setText("asda");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }

});
```

Here is layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@drawable/p2_bg_nav">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/p2_btn_nav_xml"
        android:text="Настр."
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Мои карты"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:spacing="20dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:unselectedAlpha="1.0"
    android:background="#fa0000" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/rl1"
    android:layout_above="@id/gallery"
    android:background="#d8d8d8" >

</ListView>
```

Maybe there is a way to set listener on animation stop event?

Another thing is that I have TextView on my Gallery items. TextColor is set to black, but it is black only for selected item in gallery. How I can avoid changing text color for unselected items?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like reason was that all views and gallery were linked in relative layout. After changing one view all layout redraw and gallery itself too.